# Retrieve Woocommerce Cart Url with javascript/jquery

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery, javascript

Is it possible to retrive woocommerce cart url using javascript or jquery? Are there native functions or do I have to perform an ajax call to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it to the script via the functions.php file or a plugin using the wp_localize_script function.

```
<?php
function my_load_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/my-script.js');
    wp_localize_script('my-script', 'my_script_vars', array(
            'woo_cart_url' => get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) )
        )
    );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```

Then it will be available in your script ( in the example: **my_script_vars.woo_cart_url** )

https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Tanks